# How to access HttpResponse from OnInit

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse, httpcontext, page-lifecycle

My issue is that I have a function executing in the Page.Init phase of the life cycle.

That function needs access to the HttpResponse object that the current Page has.

Trying to access it via HttpContext.current is not working because that object is null in this phase of the life cycle.

I can't construct my own HttpResponse nor do I think that is the way to solve this.

Due to the application, I can't move my function to another phase of the life cycle however, I have access to OnPreRender and OnLoad.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please confirm that you are talking about asp.net (add tag) and Page.Init event (and not application init where you really don't have access to request)? [Edit] post with that info.

Comment: Why do you need to access the `HttpResponse` in the `Init` phase? Why not wait until the `PageLoad` phase?

Comment: I'm writing a DLL that contains functions that are called in the init phase so it's beyond my control as to which phase I can execute these functions in.  I'm just wondering if it's possible to accomplish what I have to do.

Comment: I have access to OnLoad and OnPrerender only.

Comment: `I can't move my function to another phase of the life cycle however, I have access to OnPreRender and OnLoad` - So why can't you use `OnLoad` if you have access to it? [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)